# Lazily initializing object with val properties

Tags: kotlin

I am finishing refactoring of my plugin for IntelliJ written in Kotlin which is my first Kotlin project, and there is one particular place I don't like. I am looking for some nice solution before I go hacky way and force it with some 'not as Kotlin team intended' use of 'by lazy'

I have some things that I use a lot that should be initialized once project is opened:

```
object Project_State {
  // I would really like not to use vars here and have it as all walls 
  // is some 'by lazy' magic possible here?
  var project: Project? = null
  var path: String? = null
  var file_manager: FileEditorManagerEx? = null
}
```

There is an extension point that is triggered after project is open and its the earliest place where I can do initialize all the things that won't change during plugin's runtime.
If for some reason this fails I throw exception, no reason to continue, this however always succeeds so it always have non null data after overridden function is triggered by IntelliJ

```
class Context(): ProjectActivity {
  override suspend fun execute(project: Project) {
    Project_State.project = project
    Project_State.path = project.basePath
    Project_State.file_manager = FileEditorManagerEx.getInstanceEx(project)
  }
}
```

After that I am using this with null checks or non-null assertions all over the place

```
fun what_i_have() {
  create_workspace(Project_State.file_manager!!.editorSplitters)
}

fun what_i_want() {
  create_workspace(Project_State.file_manager.editorSplitters)
}
```

So in short, there is a piece of data (Project) that is accessible only during execution during execution of an extension point that is run by code I don't have under control, and I want to find nice way how to push this data into a singleton object that is available everywhere within my plugin.

I was looking into companion objects, by lazy and coroutines, but didn't find an obvious solution to this issue.

Comment: There’s `lateinit`, but I’m guessing the right way in the context of IntelliJ plugins is to do it [like this `BackgroundHighlighterProjectActivity`](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/5382595e6ba4747b7dd48e174f7957803cbab459/platform/lang-impl/src/com/intellij/codeInsight/highlighting/BackgroundHighlighterProjectActivity.kt#L27). Don’t use singletons.

Comment: Having this as an object is the problem.  Create a class, properly initialize it, pass it everywhere instead of being lazy and using `Project_State` everywhere.